# Converting .blend to a .dxf

Tags: modeling

When I google this, I mostly get online converters. I need actual answers.

I have a mesh in blender. It's 2D. It's has 0 depth, here's a top-view of a portion of it.

To try to fix this, I tried giving it some depth by extruding it. That made no change.

[image]

(I see the small defect in the blender screenshot. I've already fixed that issue)

When I convert it to DXF,  through an online converter or the Blender addon, I get a pure wireframe. It has no "faces" or solid areas, which their automated system has a problem with.

[image]

Is there something I can do to faciliate this?

I'm trying to have something milled and they want a .dxf file. They don't accept .blend, .obj, or anything like that.

Comment: I thought .dxf was for 2D _drawings_ (not meshes). Maybe check and see if the people doing the milling will accept an .stl file - it's a CAD format made for meshes.

Comment: Solid works let's you rotate a dxf much like you can in Blender. Top/left/right etc view

Comment: Yea, I dunno then. I know blender triangulates meshes when converting to dxf (with no option to not to), and that the exporter is reported to be touch and go at best (especially with reading line widths). I think your best bet would be to export to .fbx (which can be opened by AutoCAD software), or to export to .stl, and then convert the .stl to .dxf.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tomorrow.